# C# How to get required control (ImageList) while iterating through contols on a Windows Form

Tags: c#, forms, loops, imagelist

While loading a Windows Form (C#), I'm trying to iterate through all controls. So I'm writing code in 
public Form1()

I've 5 ImageList controls on my form and I want to select an ImageList control on the basis of a string expression.

Can anyone please help to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageList is not a control so you can't find them back by iterating the form's Controls collection.  "Selecting" is not a valid operation, assuming you mean setting the focus to it.  It isn't visible at runtime.

Find them back through the "components" field, like this:

```
        foreach (Component comp in this.components.Components) {
            var ilist = comp as ImageList;
            if (ilist != null) {
                // Got one, do something with it
                //...
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`ImageList` is a component, not a control.
It does not get added to any collections.

Instead, you can make your own `Dictionary<string, ImageList>` yourself.